# Show that for an abelian countable group $G$ there exists a compact path connected subspace $K ⊆ \Bbb R^4$ such that $H_1(K)$ isomorphic to $G$

Tags: compactness, homology-cohomology, fundamental-groups, path-connected

" Given an **abelian** countable group G thus there exists a compact path connected subspace $K ⊆\Bbb R^4$ such that  $H_1(K) ≅ G$ ", where $H_1$ is the first singular homology.

Can I prove it using the Theorem:" For every countable group G there exists a compact path connected subspace $K ⊆ \Bbb R^4$ such that  $π_1(K) ≅ G$."?

If i removed **abelian**, is it still right to be proved or not?

Comment: If $G$ is abeilan, $\pi_1(K) = G = G^{\rm ab} = H_1(K)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's enough. There is [a theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurewicz_theorem) which says (among other things) that $H_1(X)$ is isomorphic to the abelienization of $\pi_1(X)$ for any path connected space $X$.

If $G$ is already abelian, then we have $H_1(X)\cong \pi_1(X)$.

Comment: Can I prove it without using the Theorem?

Comment: @Rahab Of course. Use the proof of the theorem instead.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your last question:

No, if you remove abelian it will not work, since all singular homology groups are abelian, and the property of being abelian is preserved through isomorphisms.